# Update existing plist on iOS5 simulator

Tags: file, ios5, plist, simulator

I am trying to update an existing `plist` on iOS5 simulator but it fails miserably.

It finds the plist and retrieves existing information and updates the array but it does not write to file.

Any one would have any ideas?

```xcode
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content_iPhone"       ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSMutableArray *plist = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];

// For testing purpose, get an object from the Array and add the object to array
newObject = [plist objectAtIndex:1];
[plist addObject:newObject];

[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to a file inside your app bundle, you can only read from it.

You could write the file to the user's Documents directory instead: look at

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
```

This returns an array, the first object of which will be the path to the user's Documents directory for your app. You could copy the file there the first time your app is run, and update it at that location in the future.